# Alternative to ob_get_contents();?

Tags: php

Have a case where I'm trying to compare and use two variables, but which first need to be created and formatted from a datestamp.

Currently, if I use:

```
    ob_start();
    echo date_i18n('d M Y', $date_start);
    $start = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
```

I can achieve what I want. However, when I try to add a second variable, a `$date_end` (and a conditional) I get strange behavior. So my thinking is that using this twice within the same function isn't kosher. Here's what I tried :

```
if( $date_start == $date_end ) {

    ob_start();
    echo date_i18n('d M Y', $date_start);
    $start = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    $title = $start;

} else {

    ob_start();
    echo date_i18n('d M', $date_start);
    $start = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    ob_start();
    echo date_i18n('d M Y', $date_end);
    $end = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    $title = $start.' - '. $end;
}
```

Essentially, if the `$date_end` does not equals `$date_start`, then the `$start` will output correctly but the `$end` will output as TODAY'S DATE. And if `$date_end` equals `$date_start` then again, the date appears as TODAY'S DATE.

Actually using just the one date will suffice for my project, but I'm curious as to alternatives and why I would get this kind of behavior.

/*EDIT*/

the input values are:

```
$date_start = strtotime(get_field('date_debut', $post_id));
$date_end = strtotime(get_field('date_fin', $post_id));
```

Comment: I don't think you explain why you need output buffer in the first place. Without that information, it's hard to provide alternatives.

Comment: `ob_get_clean()` does both, returning the content + cleaning the output buffer at once

Comment: @Álvaro I may not. I found this as a solution for assigning my translated datestamp to a variable. The initial info is first obtained from the database like this `$date_start = strtotime(get_field('date_debut', $post_id));`So I need to go through these two steps first to retrieve the date and have it display correctly…hope that's clear.

Comment: What is `date_i18n`?? Why do you need to buffer??

Comment: @PeeHaa it's used to translate the date into local language.

Comment: You don't need buffers, `date_i18n()` returns values just fine (it's WordPress function for the context). What the issue is — impossible to say without seeing your input values.

Comment: DISCLAIMER : this isn't "pure" php. There's some WordPress mixed in :)

Comment: why `ob_start();
    echo date_i18n('d M Y', $date_start);
    $start = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();` instead of `$start = date_i18n('d M Y', $date_start);`?

Comment: @Rarst `$date_start = strtotime(get_field('date_debut', $post_id));`will return 1419120000

Comment: @Florien ha! yes! because I think I needed the echo to output in the info and this is why I'm the n00b and I needed your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Output buffer has several usages. One of them is to be able to capture the output of functions and methods that print stuff to standard output (rather than returning). In other words, functions like this:

```
function foo(){
    echo 'bar!';
}
```

... rather than this:

```
function foo(){
    return 'bar!';
}
```

We don't know how `date_i18n()` works but you *echo* its output:

```
echo date_i18n('d M Y', $date_start);
```

So I strongly suspect you're over-engineering a piece of code that could just be:

```
$start = date_i18n('d M Y', $date_start);
```

Other than that, PHP has specific types to handle dates (Unix timestamps and DateTime objects). You should not use strings to perform date manipulation logic, just like you wouldn't try to add `one` and `three`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$ts_start = strtotime( get_field( 'date_debut', $post_id ) );
$ts_end   = strtotime( get_field( 'date_fin', $post_id ) );

if ( $ts_start === $ts_end ) {
    $title = date_i18n( 'd M Y', $ts_start );
} else {
    $title = date_i18n( 'd M', $ts_start ) . ' - ' . date_i18n( 'd M Y', $ts_end );
}
```

Comment: This is still returning today's date for the end date if !=

Comment: Also if = it now is still returning two dates instead of just one :\

Comment: Turns out it was an ACF bug :)